# How to fix variable not updating in while loop (python)

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

I am making a program that guesses a number that you are thinking of by telling the program if the number is higher or lower. I'm not getting errors, but I can't seem to update the variable "guess" in the while loop, it remains equal to 50. The formula for higher-lower is given by the textbook, so I can't change that.

I have tried moving the variable inside of the while loop, but still, it does not update.

```
print('Hello.')
print('Pick a secret number between 0 and 100.')
low = 0
high = 101
guess = 50
while True:
    print('Is your secret number',guess)
    use = input('Enter yes/higher/lower:\n').lower()
    if use == 'yes':
        print('Great!')
        break
    elif use == 'higher':
        low = guess
        guess = (guess-low)//2+low
    elif use == 'lower':
        high = guess
        guess = (high-guess)//2+guess
    else:
        print('I did not understand.')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, `low`, `high`, and `guess` needs to be updated for each loop. Your new `guess` should be the mean of your new `low` and `high`.

As is, your guess remains the same. For instance if the user responds with `'higher'`, `guess-low` is `0`. Divide by `2` is still `0`, then add by `low`, which is `guess`.

You likely want this:

```
low = guess
guess = (high + low) // 2
```

and

```
high =  guess
guess = (high + low) // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the logic you used is wrong.

Right now, what's happening is,

```
low = guess
guess = (guess - low) // 2 + low
```

As `low = guess` the above statement is equivalent to,

```
guess = (guess - guess) // 2 + low
# guess = 0 + low
# guess = low
```

Similarly, for high,

```
high = guess
guess = (high - guess) //2 + guess
```

As `high = guess` the above statement is equivalent to,

```
guess = (high - high) // 2 + guess
# guess = 0 + guess
# guess = guess
```

That's why it's always stuck on `50`.

---

The actual logic for it to work is as follows,

```
elif use == 'higher':
    low = guess
    guess = (guess + high) // 2
elif use == 'lower':
    high = guess
    guess = (guess + low) // 2
```

Change the snippet to this. It will work!

---

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

That's weird, because there's something wrong with your formula.

```
    elif use == 'higher':
        low = guess
        guess = (guess-low)//2+low
    elif use == 'lower':
        high = guess
        guess = (high-guess)//2+guess
```

In this part, since `low == high == guess`, the result of `guess - low` and `high - guess` will always be 0. Dividing that by 2 also gives 0. Therefore, both lines become equivalent to `guess = guess`.

This is because you are reassigning to `low` and `high`, which I believe you mean to hold the lower and upper limits of the guessing range.

Perhaps you mean `guess += (high - guess) // 2` and `guess -= (guess - low) // 2`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be variable 'value reallocation' (I'm not sure for this word I'm French), with Equals :

> =

you must use

> guess += value

or

> guess = guess  + guess

or

> guess = guess - guess

or

> guess -= guess